# Apply new CSS rules when on click of <a> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, combinators

I'm currently trying to design and develop my own lightweight lightbox. The idea is when someone clicks `<a href="#tab1">` it will change the properties of the `<div id="tab1">` from `display: none` to `display: block`. Once the lightbox pops up it will have another link like `<a href="#tab1_close">` to reverse the CSS properties back to `display: none`.

I've used `input[name='name'] ~ #id` for a lot of other sections on my site, I'm wondering if it's possible to change it so the input recognizes the `<a>` as the input and applies the CSS changes on the click.

Ideally, I could add `id="tab_1"` to the `<a>`, then the code would be something like `a#tab_1:active ~ #tab1 { display: block }` but that code doesn't seem to do anything.

[**Here's my Code Pen**](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/sAfEH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want CSS only try the `:target` selector:

```
#tab1:target {
  display: block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/okEqr

Comment: Awesome! Oddly enough, I didn't even know `:target` was a pseudo class. This does exactly what I was looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's toggleClass() will dow hat you want: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/